# Android - Unit test with Livedata and Firebase

Tags: android, unit-testing, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using a `FirebaseQueryLiveData`, class who add a `SnapshotListener` in a `query` and receive events from Firebase Firestore.

Base on that, I want to make a unit test for this one. But I dont know how to do it.

I have made something like:

```
val productsLiveData = productGridViewModel.myMediatorLiveData
assert(productsLiveData.value!!.isNotEmpty())
```

But I dont think its make any sense, because I need to have a observer listening to my `LiveData list` right?

Do you guys can provide some example for me, please?